# Connect to a SQL Server database from MS Access

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, esri-geodatabase, ms-access

I have an existing Microsoft SQL Server database which has been configured as an Enterprise geodatabase. I want to access it in MS Access in order to extract data to populate a form.  What is the proper way to connect it? I have an ArcGIS Enterprise connection file named:
"G:\Database Connections\eGIS_Cadastral on EGISDBP1 as viewer.sde"

So far I went to new data source > from other source > odbc database and chose Link data source. It now wants a file data source. What is that?

Here is an image on where I am stuck:

[image]

This is an image of the connection properties in ArcMap:

[image]

Comment: To what 'DNS' are you referring?  Domain Name Service isn't file-oriented, although it uses a hosts file as a resource

Comment: I am not sure where you insert the host file. I am stuck at the part of selecting the data source.

Comment: I tried to click new and now wants a ODBC File Data Source. Is that the host file?

Comment: Please [Edit] this question to clarify the task you are attemping to complete

Comment: Hello Vince. I have edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean Access, the software, or just access? This still isn't as clear as it could be.  You have an existing Microsoft SQL Server database, which has been configured as an Enterprise geodatabase.  Now you want to access it from ________ in order to _________, and the reduced functional access that will result is okay because ________.  You might find that ODBC is more of an [so] or [dba.se] issue.

Comment: Thanks again Vince. I followed your advice on how to describe the issue in the last revision. I will also visit the dba forum as you suggested.

Comment: The connection properties in the earlier graphic probably would have been of more use than just the .sde file name.

Comment: Hell o Vince. I reattached the earlier image.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the ODBC in Windows to add the proper driver and set-up the DNS.

Comment: This is similar to a link-only answer, except it doesn't have a link. Please provide details to expand upon the steps necessary.